# Why sqlalchemy session remains open, even if lambda timesout

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aws-lambda

I am testing SQL Alchemy on AWS Lambda. Engine and session are in a singleton. According to the observed behavior, my question is why in AWS Lambda, SQL Alchemy session remains there even after Lambda times out.

To test that session remains there, I used following steps:

With postgres as db I started a transaction and ran drop query but didn't committed nor rolled back it. Did this in workbenchJ.

Now I invoked lambda and in lambda I run select query on the same table.

As in postgres select and drop cannot run concurrently so now you can check the that select statement is waiting for the lock acquired by drop query.

Comment: How do you know that the session remains? Are you looking at sessions from the DB side?

Comment: @9000 Question updated.

Comment: are you creating your connection outside of the handler function?

Comment: not exactly outside the handler function. I have a singleton class DbUtility which I use inside handler function.

Comment: Since a lambda's process is not necessarily shut down between executions, the connection in the singleton class may persist.

Answer (score 6):

When a `Lambda` function is invoked, one `Lambda` concurrency is created. 
You can think of the concurrency as like a container.

After a `Lambda` is timed out or even finished normally, the concurrency will be alive for a while(maybe 10~30min). It means that the memory area also still be retained. It is to react fast against continual invocation because booting up concurrency takes a time.

Thus, If another invocation is requested, the concurrency is reused with the same memory area.

That is why your `sqlalchemy` session is still alive on the next invocation.

However, If another invocation is requested while one concurrency is running, the other concurrency is created not sharing memory area. At that time, your `sqlalchemy` session is not there.

You can check with the small example.
Invoke the `Lambda` function 10 times at 1-sec interval respectively and check the output. Two functions will show different results.

```
variable = 10

def lambda_function(event, context):
    global variable
    print(variable)  
    variable += 1

# output: the variable increase because it reuse memory.
10
11
12
13
14
.
.
.
```

---

```
import time

variable = 10

def lambda_function(event, context):
    global variable
    print(variable)  
    variable += 1
    time.sleep(60)  # Lambda timeout also should be long enough

# output: the variable doesn't increase because new concurrency is used while previous concurrencies are pending at sleep(60)
10
10
10
10
.
.
```

Additionally, you can check how many concurrencies are running now in `CloudWatch`.

Comment: How can I replicate such a thing. sort of a small POC without using sqlalchemy

Comment: @ArslanAnjum I add a simple example to help your understanding.